# Bash rename music tracks

Tags: bash

I have a folder with around 80 music tracks.

I would like to rename them from "Artist - Title" to "01. Artist - Title" all the way through 80.

I can't quite figure out how to do this, so could someone help?

Comment: I would cp the files in a for loop, put the file name in a variable old_name then name the new files i+"old_name", then delete the original files. Use i++ and the value of i changes.

Comment: Does i++ work in bash? I think it threw an error

Comment: sorry, no it's i = i+1. @Hotpil wrote the script in his answer.

Comment: In what order do you want to assign the numbers? Alphabetically by Artist and Title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several others have pointed out that doing this strictly inside of bash might not be what you want, because it might confuse any Music programs you have that manage the library themselves.

In any case, here's how you can do it in bash:

```
i=0
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" $(printf '%02d. %s' $i "$f")
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

The double-quotes around `$f` are vital because the file names are sure to contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you still need it, but anyway:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
for file in *
do
  mv "$file" "$i.$file"
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: This does not zero-pad files as requested by the OP, so it won't sort nicely.

Answer (score -2):

Updated :

What you need is a software that mass rename music files or tags (inside the file) for you.

I would suggest a specific tool for that quantity of music files, a free tool named Mp3Tag.
It does what you ask and even more.

http://www.mp3tag.de/en/

This software would enable you to rename or replace not only any part of the file name according to the mp3 tags encoded within each files but also rename files incrementally you can customize the way it works either numerically (01,02 etc) or alphabetically (AA, AB etc...) as prefix or suffix.

It does also work the other way around by using the filenames to change the Tags

And finally it can go online and fill the tags for you if some are missing or you would like to replace them automatically.

Let me know if it answers your question.
have a good one.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline. In addition, please be careful posting links in answers of this nature—they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise. See the [help/behavior] for more information.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I will try to make my answer better.

Comment: Considering its bash, I suspect the OP needs a linux based tool

Comment: the same idea is applicable for linux as there are linux version of tools like that.  but i am seeing that giving potentially good answer is not enough to be on site that is my first impression and is going to be my last.